# Angular 2 TS - On POST getting undefined on server

Tags: javascript, express, angular

I'm trying to post **"uid"** but server showing **"undefined"**, I don't know why this is happening!! Even I set headers properly,  it still does not work, please help me out.

Here the code of application :

**HTML**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  User Id: <input type="text" name="uid" [(ngModel)] = 'uid'>  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**onSubmit** function

```
onSubmit(value) {
  var headers = new Headers();
  var data = { uid: this.uid };
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.http.post('http://192.168.50.193:1000/process_post', JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers})
      .subscribe((data)=>
          console.log("POST::: "+data);
      );
}
```

**server.js** (express) post method here:

```js
app.post('process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
   response = {
       first_name:req.body.uid
   };
   console.log(req.body.uid);
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```

After clicking on **Submit** command prompt I'm getting **'undefined'**, why ?

Comment: Is `this.uid` undefined in the `onSubmit()` method? Can you try to replicate the request with [`Postman`](https://www.getpostman.com/) - do you get there `undefined` too?

Comment: could you try to do `console.log(this.uid)` inside `onSubmit` method

Comment: Yes, Im getting proper value using **'this.uid'** on **onSubmit()** method.

Comment: but at server side request body is showing empty.

Comment: @rinukkusu, I tried with postman, its giving blank **{} body** on response.

Comment: Check the request in browser DevTools -> Network Tab. Make sure it contains correct inputs. If **Postman** gives you empty result, then it's server-side doing something wrong

Comment: Also I think `urlencodedParser` is the wrong tool here ... you probably need [`body-parser-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser-json)

Comment: @rinukkusu, thanks a lot, I've used **'app.use(bodyParser.json())'**, and its working... thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `map` method:

```
onSubmit(value) {
  var headers = new Headers();
  var data = { uid: this.uid };
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.http.post('http://192.168.50.193:1000/process_post', JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers})
      .map(data => data.json())
      .subscribe((data)=>
          console.log("POST::: "+data);
      );
}
```